# Understanding SPF and mail forwarding

Tags: email, gmail, postfix-mta, spf

Situation:

- i use my own mydomain.de for sending and receiving mails
- my mail is info@mydomain.de
- mydomain.de is not a relay
- i forward received mails via postfix alias to a gmail account

  - the alias info@mydomain.de -> myname@gmail.com
- mydomain.de has an SPF entry: `v=spf1 mx -all`
- mx entry on mydomain.de is: mydomain.de

Problem:
Sometimes gmail rejects the emails forwarded from my postfix.

```
E624BAC: to=<myname@gmail.com>, orig_to=<info@mydomain.de>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.250.102.26]:25, delay=1.1, delays=0.51/0.04/0.11/0.41, dsn=5.7.26, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.250.102.26] said: 550-5.7.26 The MAIL FROM domain [some-sender-domain.de] has an SPF record 550-5.7.26 with a hard fail policy (-all) but it fails to pass SPF checks with 550-5.7.26 the ip: [MY-IP-ADDRESS]. To best protect our users from spam and 550-5.7.26 phishing, the message has been blocked. Please visit 550-5.7.26  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more 550 5.7.26 information. de37-20020a1709069be500b23421fc6a72f7si8409808ejc.679 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))
```

The some-sender-domain.de has it's own SPF entry.

- What is the problem?
- Why is gmail thinking that this is not a forwarded mail, but a mail originating from my server? Sure the SPF check fails in that case.
- How can i fix that?

Comment: As the postfix tag states: QUESTIONS ABOUT POSTFIX ADMINISTRATION ARE OFF-TOPIC. Server admin questions may be asked on Server Fault. Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

Your SPF only allows sending from your MX (i.e. the destination for *inbound* messages), but you're sending from somewhere that's not your MX.

Add your IP to your SPF:

```
v=spf1 ip4:x.x.x.x mx -all
```

(it's fastest for receivers to check SPF if you put literal IPs first, as they require no DNS lookups)

or (if it points to the same IP) an `a` mechanism to your SPF:

```
v=spf1 a mx -all
```

Or if those places are not the same, add both:

```
v=spf1 ip4:x.x.x.x a mx -all
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i'm sending only from my mx which is in SPF and i also forward mails. For ex. johndoe@yahoo.com is writing to me info@mydomain.de. I forward his mail to my gmail box.

Comment: If the mx was the IP you were sending from, you would not be getting the error. I recommend checking it from [this form](https://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html?) (by the creator of SPF).

Comment: I think it's still unclear:

mydomain.de - has own spf;
senders some-sender-domain.de - has it's own spf allowing to send mails only from his mx;

So when user@some-sender-domain.de writes to my info@mydomain.de i forward this to my gmail - gmail rejects with an spf fail.

Comment: If you are forwarding a message with an envelope sender in `some-sender-domain.de`, that domain needs an `include:mydomain.de` in their SPF so that they give permission for your server to send email from their domain.

Comment: Hi, yes - that is the problem, i cannot ask every sender in the world to add my mydomain.de to his spf policy. But here is the solution: postsrsd. Here is exactly the same problem: https://serverfault.com/questions/1113736/forwarding-to-gmail-account-via-postfix-spf-record-with-a-hard-fail 

@synchro: thanks!

Comment: @Synchro not `include` but `mx`. On the premise that the IP addresses under the MX of mydomain.de send the email.

@dr0bz: if you're forwarding whilst preserving the senders email address, then you're going to have this issue without any exception. In this case you'd rather change the sender email address to `forward@mydomain.de` These practices will get your IP address banned from GMail.